# Ligatures with cufon

Tags: fonts, cufon, ligature

Has anyone managed to use ligatures with Cufon? I have a converted open type font (Knockout, checked "All glyphs", added "œ" manually to glyphs), but œ always shows up as "u".

All I find are some pull requests, but the current state is not clear. it seems pulled in, but what do I need to do to use it?

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/issues/38 and 
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/pull/233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should read a bit more, so here, for your reference:

1.10 (development version): [NEW] Configurable support for basic ligatures. Thanks mdumic!

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Changelog

Comment: aaaaaaahhh, those were the times, `cufon` to the rescue, it was!